# How to implement an interface member that returns void in F#

Tags: interface, compiler-errors, f#, void, unit-type

Imagine the following interface in C#:

```
interface IFoo {
    void Bar();
}
```

How can I implement this in F#?  All the examples I've found during 30 minutes of searching online show only examples that have return types which I suppose is more common in a functional style, but something I can't avoid in this instance.

Here's what I have so far:

```
type Bar() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar() =
            void
```

Fails with _FS0010:

> Unexpected keyword 'void' in expression_.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivalent is unit which is syntactically defined as `()`.

```
type Bar() =
    interface IFoo with
        member this.Bar () = ()
```

Comment: @Drew - It is an awesome language.

Comment: The C# code was a method, not a property. To reproduce this in F#, I believe you need a member with signature unit -> unit. This would be written "member this.Bar () = ()". Without the unit parameter, the F# could would be a property with a getter.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks, it is safe to assume that @Drew implicitly corrected my mistake.

Comment: @Jason, you're right.  Actually my method took arguments (and surprisingly wasn't called Bar!) so I'd messed up transcribing it in the original question.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Drew - Wait your method wasn't named Bar? That is a production quality method name... :)

Answer (score 7):

For general info on F# types, see

[The basic syntax of F# - types](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1077.entry)

From that page:

> The **unit** type has only one value, written "()".  It is a little bit like "void", in the sense that if you have a function that you only call for side-effects (e.g. printf), such a function will have a return type of "unit".  Every function takes an argument and returns a result, so you use "unit" to signify that the argument/result is uninteresting/meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I included a quote from the page in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The return type needs to be (), so something like *member this.Bar = ()* should do the trick

Comment: To be pedantic, the return _type_ is `unit`, the only _value_ of that type is spelled `()`.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in F# is:

```
type IFoo =
    abstract member Bar: unit -> unit
```