# Why do I need to use the unit type in F# if it supports the void type?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, void, lambda, unit-type

I read this MSDN article:

[Unit Type (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx)

> ...The unit type is a type that indicates the absence of a specific
>   value; the unit type has only a single value, which acts as a
>   placeholder when no other value exists or is needed ...
>   The unit type resembles the void type in languages such as C# and C++...

So... Alright, I understand, that the unit type is such a type, which has only a single value `()`. But I have some questions:

1. Why is it needed?
2. When is it needed?

I don't understand why not to use the void type in F#, like C# and C++ use.

If I look at the following table:

[Primitive Types (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233210.aspx)

```
Type   .NET Type    Description  
void   Void         Indicates no type or value.
```

I see that F# does have a void type. So I don't understand why the unit type needed; it looks like it is very similar to void.

I suppose that it relates to the functional language paradigm and that's why it's needed, so please... explain more about this to me.

Comment: See: [What does this '()' notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17872004/1243762)

Comment: I've read you answer to other question, it's great :) but I have a new question you. If I use the next code: `let b () = System.DateTime.Now;;System.Console.WriteLine(b);;`, why is it returning `Program+clo@16` in console output and what's it?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067605/how-to-implement-an-interface-member-that-returns-void-in-f) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900962/void-in-constrast-with-unit)

Comment: Because b is bound to a function. You can call it with b()

Comment: It should be `System.Console.Writeline(b());;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C#, there is no value of type `void` that can be used as an argument type.  Furthermore, `void` can't be used as a generic type argument (so for example C# needs to use parallel `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` delegate types, but F# needs only a single function type `... -> ...` which can abstract over both).  This ends up greatly simplifying F# programming in many cases; for example, an `Async` action which performs some side effects but doesn't return a value is an instance of type `Async<unit>`, but in C# there's no way to create a corresponding `Task<void>` or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

See [Unit Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) from Wikipedia

> **Void type as unit type**
>
> In C, C++, C#, and Java, void expresses the empty type. The unit type
>   in C would be struct {}, but an empty struct is forbidden by the C
>   language specification. Instead void is used in a manner that
>   simulates some, but not all, of the properties of the unit type, as
>   detailed below.
>
> **Difference in calling convention**
>
> The first notable difference between a true unit type and the void
>   type is that the unit type may always be the type of the argument to a
>   function, but the void type cannot be the type of an argument in C,
>   despite the fact that it may appear as the sole argument in the list.
>
> **Difference in storage**
>
> The second notable difference is that the void type, being empty, can
>   never be stored in a record type, i.e. in a struct or a class in
>   C/C++. In contrast, the unit type can be stored in records in
>   functional programming languages, i.e. it can appear as the type of a
>   field; the above implementation of the unit type in C++ can also be
>   stored. While this may seem a useless feature, it does allow one for
>   instance to elegantly implement a set as a map to the unit type; in
>   the absence of a unit type, one can still implement a set this way by
>   storing some dummy value of another type for each key.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to look at it is to visualize () as a tuple with arity of 0.

Given that () is used to delimit a tuple, we get

```
(abc, def, xyx) a tuple with arity of 3
(abc, def) a tuple with arity of 2
(abc) a tuple with arity of 1, which can be reduced to abc
() a tuple with arity of 0, called unit
```

In functional languages based on the lambda calculus, a function takes a single parameter and returns a single value. Multiple parameters are supported by currying. Parameters and return values can also be tuples to support multiple values.

My interpretation of unit / (), is no values, expressed as a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

This article explains some limitations of `void` and why you even might want to have `Unit` in C#: https://chtenb.dev/?page=unit-cs

The bottom line is that you can't use `void` as a type parameter in generic types, like `Task<void>`. Using a unit type instead of void solves this problem.

This is the Unit implementation used in the article.

```cs
public struct Unit : IEquatable<Unit>
{
  public static readonly Unit unit;
  public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Unit;
  public override int GetHashCode() => 0;
  public static bool operator ==(Unit left, Unit right) => left.Equals(right);
  public static bool operator !=(Unit left, Unit right) => !(left == right);
  public bool Equals(Unit other) => true;
  public override string ToString() => "()";
}
```

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. You should put all of the salient details in the answer itself and only link to support your content.

Comment: I know that the article defines `Unit.unit` because it can't do `Unit.Unit`, but I'd suggest `Unit.Default` instead to stick with the normal C# naming convention. Also, adding `public override string ToString() => "()";` would be a nice touch.

Comment: Microsoft's Reactive Framework also has an implementation - I'd trust that one. Here it is: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Unit.cs

Comment: The reason I chose `unit` is so you can do `using static Unit;` and then use `unit` everywhere as if it where a builtin type. Also because it's brief. I did not know the reactive framework had a similar one.

Comment: What would've been nice is if `()` was valid syntax for the empty valuetuple. We could then setup implicit conversion operators to make it a unit automatically. 

You could also use `default` to refer to unit btw.