# What do the empty parentheses `()` mean in Elm?

Tags: functional-programming, elm, unit-type

I found out they are mean an empty tuple. However, are they also used as a convention by Elm programmers to mean "value can be ignored"?

```
is13 : Int -> Result String ()
is13 code =
  if code == 13 then Ok () else Err "not the right key code"
```

Source: https://github.com/pdamoc/elmChallenges/blob/master/challenge5.elm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The empty parentheses `()` are what's known as a *unit* type, that is, a type that can only ever have a single value. A tuple type with at least one item can have any number of values (for example, a type defined as a tuple of one `Int` could have an infinite number of values, from `(-∞)` to `(+∞)`). But how many possible values of "the empty tuple" are there? Just one, hence why it's called a *unit* type.

The value of a unit type is that you can use it in places where other languages would have a `null` or `void` type, while avoiding the problems that `null` carries with it. For example, as you've noticed, it's often used in places where you want to say "I don't care what the value is". **But** there is a value there; it's not the absence of a value.

This has many advantages; for example, you can say "**ALL** functions return a value", and this will be true. Sometimes the value is one you don't care about, but **all** functions will return a value. In languages with a `void` type, you can't say that. For example, C# has two different ways to declare a function delegate: `Func<T>` for a function returning type `T`, and `Action` for a function returning `void`. In Elm (and F#, and other functional languages that use a unit type), there's no need for that distinction: all functions return a value, so all functions could be treated as the equivalent of `Func<T>`. Sometimes type `T` is the empty tuple, but it means that you don't have to write two versions of, say, `map`.

Another advantage is that it lets you compose functions more easily. Here's an example taken from [the Wikipedia page on unit types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). In C, you can't do this:

```
void f(void) {}
void g(void) {}

int main(void)
{
  f(g()); // compile-time error here
  return 0;
}
```

This is an error, because you're not allowed to pass `void` as a parameter: it's the *absence* of a value. Which means that you can't use standard function composition to chain functions `f` and `g` together. But here's another snippet from the same article, of C++ this time, showing what it *would* look like if you gave C++ an Elm-like unit type:

```
class unit_type {};
const unit_type the_unit;

unit_type f(unit_type) { return the_unit; }
unit_type g(unit_type) { return the_unit; }

int main()
{
  f(g(the_unit));
  return 0;
}
```

Now, because `g` returns a real value (even though it's one you don't care about), you can compose `f` and `g` meaningfully. This makes your program more elegant and easy to read in the long run.

Some further reading that might help you:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type (which I've already linked once in this answer)
2. [Why do I need to use the unit type in F# if it supports the void type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20704860/2314532)

Hope this helps!