# Why is `System.Void` different from `unit` type?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

> [F# Types Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-types) said that:
>
> [Unit Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type): Describes the `unit` type, a type that has one value and that is indicated by (); equivalent to `void` in C# and `Nothing` in Visual Basic.

It said they're equal, but why does the following comparison return false?

```
typedefof<System.Void> = typedefof<unit>;;
val it : bool = false
```

Comment: I guess it’s because `Sustem.Void` cannot be used as a the parameter for generic types. That’s why we have both `Task` and `Task<T>` where’s F# allows us to have only `Async<'T>`.

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704860/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-unit-type-in-f-if-it-supports-the-void-type) and [there](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2012/01/action-func-void-and-unit.html)

Comment: *Equivalent* and *equal* are different things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, they're not really equivalent. The quote you posted is a bit misleading.

The F# type `unit` is equivalent to C# *keyword* `void` (not the type `System.Void`!) in that both the type and the keyword are used to declare functions that don't return anything:

```
// F#
let f (x:int) : unit = ...

// C#
void f( int x ) { ... }
```

This is what your quote is talking about, but the equivalence stops there.

In C# `void` is not really a type. It's a keyword that is used to declare return-less methods, but you can't use it in type positions - e.g. you can't have `void` variables, parameters, type parameters, etc. That's why we have a separate delegate `Action` instead of just using `Func<void>`.

The type `System.Void` is a different animal altogether: it exist only to support reflection, but it's *not* the same as `void`, the way `System.Int32` is the same as `int`.

In F#, on the other hand, the type `unit` is mostly just a regular type, like any other. It even has a [definition in the standard library](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L27). Yes, the compiler does give it some special treatment in certain special cases, but that's only for optimization and interop, invisible at the language level. 
Consequently, `unit` can be used in any type position - parameters, variables, whatever. This means that F#, for example, doesn't need a special function type for functions that don't return anything, it can just use `int -> unit`.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar but not the same. However the compiler will compile a function with the unit parameter as void function. Unit is a special type in Functional Programming, unlike void. Also, you shouldn't be surprised by the comparison returning false, as this is void:

> val it : Type =   System.Void
>       {Assembly = mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;
>        AssemblyQualifiedName = "System.Void, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

and this is unit:

> val it : Type =   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit
>       {Assembly = FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;
>        AssemblyQualifiedName = "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";

Quite clearly they are not the same. For more see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) for example.

Comment: Not relate to the question but how could you print the full description of types?

Comment: @MiP What do you mean? Just `typedefof<System.Void>` or any 'T.